# Automate sending messages using whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, tasker, automation

I want to automatically send a whatsapp message to a specific number on a specific time every day. How can I accomplish this?

I toyed around with tasker but since I'm a newbie I haven't yet figured a way.

Any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

*CAUTION: Doesn't use Tasker.*

Take a look at [[WhatsApp] Scheduler ROOT BETA](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seebye.whatsapp.scheduler). It lets you schedule messages, and also lets you specify the frequency (once, every minutes, hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, anually, steps). Requires root access.

Comment: Any good reason for the caution?

Comment: @Firelord OP is looking for a Tasker solution. This isn't a Tasker solution. It should probably be "NOTE", instead of "CAUTION".